# change querystring value with jquery

Tags: jquery

i am using a jquery Script to create a Tab Panel. Now, what i need is to change the querystring value on click on each tab. can we do this without page refresh.

I am using below script for tab panel.

```
function tabPanel() {
    var tabContent = $('div.tabsBG > div.tabsWrapper');
    tabContent.hide().filter(':first').show();

    $('ul#tabLinks li a').click(function(){
        tabContent.hide();
        tabContent.filter(this.hash).show();
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('tabactive');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
}
```

Dummy URL of the page:
http://www.anyurl.com/tabpage.aspx?tabid=1

So, i need to change the TabID on click on tabs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is through the [HTML 5 history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method) which has [limited support](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the hash `#` instead of the query string and get the hash value with document.location.hash:

```
window.location.hash='foo'
```